# Retina display problems when working with images

Tags: objective-c, macos, retina-display, nsimage

I have met problems when working on retina display. NSImage size is correct, but if I create NSBitmapImageRep from it and write it to file I get image witch's size is twice as big as original image. There is no such problem when I use it on non retina display.

- I create NSImage from file (1920x1080)
- I do some drawings on
- I create NSBitmapImageRep from image with drawings
- I write it to file
- I get image with 3840x2160 dimensions

What could cause that?

---

```
NSImage *originalImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl];

NSImage *editedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:originalImage.size];

[editedImage lockFocus];
//I draw here NSBezierPaths
[editedImage unlockFocus];

NSBitmapImageRep *savingRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithData:[editedImage TIFFRepresentation]];
NSData *savingData = [savingRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
[savingData writeToFile:desiredFileLocationAndName atomically:no];
```

---

If I open image and save it without editing I get the correct dimensions image

```
NSImage *imageFromFile = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
NSBitmapImageRep *newRepresentation = [[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithData:[imageFromFile TIFFRepresentation]];
NSData *savingData = [newRepresentation representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
[savingData writeToFile:desiredFileLocationAndName atomically:no];
```

Comment: Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17510651/1159775

Answer (score 1):

A bitmap representation of the image is measured in pixels. It *is* twice the size. The NSImage is giving you a size in points which on retina devices measure 2 pixels per point. There is nothing wrong with what its giving you.

Comment: Is there something in particular you need to do that the new dimensions are making difficult?

Comment: The problem is that when I open image and process it with my app, then when I save image I get it twice as big as it was before in pixels. And I need to maintain original image size.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for each of those steps. I think there is a flag you can set to avoid that issue.

Comment: I have noticed that without doing any drawings I get correct image dimensions.