# how to get png representation of an NSImage object in Swift

Tags: swift

I know I can use "UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImagexxx)" to get the png representation of a UIImage object.
But I'm not sure how I can do something similar for NSImage. I could only find TIFFRepresentation available for NSImage objects.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507170/how-to-save-png-file-from-nsimage-retina-issues

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm now working on it. I'm not clear why I cannot use the function like "representationUsingType( NSBitmapFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: nil) " It says that [NSObject: AnyObject] does not conform to protocol "NilLiteralConvertible". I searched on google about this but it seems that I should be able to use it as metioned above. Do you know why this happens ? Thanks

Comment: You should open a new question and post the code. It has to do with optionals but hard to tell in a short comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help with cross-platform code, I implemented a version of`UIImagePNGRepresentation()` that runs on Mac (and uses `NSImage`):

```
#if os(macOS)

public func UIImagePNGRepresentation(_ image: NSImage) -> Data? {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
        else { return nil }
    let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImage)
    imageRep.size = image.size // display size in points
    return imageRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
}

#endif
```