# MacOS - How to programmatically count bytes for an image in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, image, count, byte

In my iOS project, in order to count bytes for my png image called "toto" I use this line below in the console:

print(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "toto").pngData()!.count)

But for my MacOS project, UIImage cannot be used so what equivalent can I use to achieve the same result?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the resulting information?The byte count can vary drastically dependng on the format you're measuring.

Comment: I understand that i would find different results depending on the format.
In a group of images I incerted many identical empty png images 1px X 1px with normal images.
I just wanted to display the normale images that are not empty.
By using the answers it works fine.

Comment: That sounds ... strange. You should consider posting it to codereview.stackexchange.come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already noticed there is no `pngData` method for `NSImage`. You need to first get the image `tiffRepresentation`, initialize a new `NSBitmapImageRep` object and get the `png` storageType representation:

---

```
let data = NSBitmapImageRep(data: NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "toto").tiffRepresentation!)!.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])!
print(data.count)
```

Comment: Thank you Leo for telling me to start with tiff and then use png.

Comment: Thank you Leo for telling me to start with tiff and then use png. For the same image the count result is for iOS (3553) => print(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "toto").pngData()!.count)  // for MacOS with tiff only (9360) => print(NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "toto").tiffRepresentation!.count) // and for MacOS with tiff+png (3463) => print(NSBitmapImageRep(data: NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image1Min").tiffRepresentation!)!.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])!) // Anyway I just needed to count for my project . Thanks Rui and Leo.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS equivalente of UIImage is [NSImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage)

edit:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510651/4334526) is something similar.
Seems that you need to get a `NSBitmapImageRep` and then use `NSBitmapImageRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])`

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me this answer that allows me to find a close equivalent (I could not find the png option but at least with the tiff option I could count and that is what I needed: print(NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "toto").tiffRepresentation!.count)

Comment: your last edit based on my post makes my answer pointless