# CoreData transient transformable image attribute that supports iOS and macOS

Tags: core-data, transformable

I have a transient attribute that holds a pointer to an image. The class of that image is specified in the core data model file as `UIImage` but I need to also support `NSImage`.

How would I support both if the model file is asking me for the class name and the module name?

[image]

## EDIT

My model is backed by core data, so I am using a scheme that Apple recommends to ensure my local persistence plays nicely with iCloud.

[image]

Comment: Replace the transient property with a property that holds a url to the image?

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson definitely an alternative choice if this doesn't workout.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I'd change it from a transformable to a binary data property, and then save PNG or JPG data in the property. Transformable isn't a good choice here because it encodes the class name with the image data (along with whatever other data the class decides to include when encoding itself).

With `UIImage` this is pretty simple-- you can use `pngData()` to get the data and `init(data:)` to convert back. With `NSImage` it's slightly less convenient but not hard. There are numerous examples here on SO that explain the steps, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510651/43832).

Comment: Thanks @Tom I failed to mention that my scheme is backed by CloudKit. Have updated my post.

Comment: @bobby123uk Same answer, this is what I’d do with or without CloudKit

Comment: I see your point and I can't disagree with you. Thanks for your input on this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a typealias for the type.

```
#if os(iOS)
import UIKit
public typealias RNImage = UIImage
#elseif os(macOS)
import Cocoa
public typealias RNImage = NSImage
#endif

final class ImagePersistenceTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    
    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return RNImage.self
    }
    
    override class var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [RNImage.self]
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else {
            fatalError("Wrong data type: value must be a Data object; received \(type(of: value))")
        }
        return super.transformedValue(data)
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let image = value as? RNImage else {
            fatalError("Wrong data type: value must be an RNImage object; received \(type(of: value))")
        }
        return super.reverseTransformedValue(image)
    }
}
```

[image]